# Assign letters to areas

Tags: excel, excel-formula, lookup, worksheet-function

I'm a little stuck on an Excel question where I am required to assign certain locations (A, B, C, D, E and F) to output `North`, `Centre` and `South` in the column called 'Area'.

For example I am told that:
 if any individual works in location `A`, `C` or `D` that would be classified as `South`.
 If the work area is `B` and `E` then it would be `Centre`.
 And finally if anyone works in area `F` then it would be `North`.

How should my external cells look?

Comment: Can you attach a screenshot of the layout. I don't quite get it with the description. Use imgur.com to host an image.

Comment: Check out the IF() formula.

Comment: Sure my bad hard to explain :D http://imgur.com/FfeA67B

Comment: also check out the AND and OR formula - `IF(AND(workarea="A",workarea="B"),"Centre","Somewhere else")`

Comment: I know how to use IF(AND... but here I have 3 conditions which is why I'm a little lost

Comment: You can put more than two terms within the AND function...

Comment: A small lookup table and `VLOOKUP()` will do this.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the area letter to be assigned is in A1,

One way:

```
=IF(A1="F","North",IF(OR(A1="B",A1="E"),"Centre","South"))
```

This is probably the closest to what you were attempting. `South` was left as a default value to save specifying three letters for it (`A`, `C` and `D` - `North` and `Centre` only required three between them).

Another way:

```
=CHOOSE(CODE(A1)-64,"South","Centre","South","South","Centre","North")
```

This converts the letter into its code number and then deducts 64 (so `A` gives rise to `1`, `B` to `2` etc.) and then feeds that as the choice to be selected from the options shown.

A third way:

```
=LOOKUP(R1,{"A","B","C","D","E","F"},{"South","Centre","South","South","Centre","North"})
```

Similar to the second way but without the character code conversion. A formula version of what is more often achieved with a lookup table (below).

A fourth way:

```
 =VLOOKUP(A1,AreaTable,2,0)
```

This as mentioned by @Tim Williams. `AreaTable` was my choice of name for a [Named Range](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Define-and-use-names-in-formulas-4d0f13ac-53b7-422e-afd2-abd7ff379c64) comprising `A` to `F` in sequence in one column and in the column immediately to the right of that (matching rows) the same "South", "Centre", .... , "North".

[IF](https://support.office.com/en-US/article/IF-function-69AED7C9-4E8A-4755-A9BC-AA8BBFF73BE2)
[OR](https://support.office.com/en-US/article/OR-function-7D17AD14-8700-4281-B308-00B131E22AF0)
[CHOOSE](https://support.office.com/en-US/article/CHOOSE-function-FC5C184F-CB62-4EC7-A46E-38653B98F5BC)
[CODE](https://support.office.com/en-US/article/CODE-function-C32B692B-2ED0-4A04-BDD9-75640144B928)
[VLOOKUP](https://support.office.com/en-US/article/VLOOKUP-function-0BBC8083-26FE-4963-8AB8-93A18AD188A1)

There are other ways such as, instead of the vertical Named Range, a horizontal one and [HLOOKUP](https://support.office.com/en-US/article/HLOOKUP-function-A3034EEC-B719-4BA3-BB65-E1AD662ED95F).